# How to add JQUERY function to phpfox?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpfox

I'm a newbie to php fox. i want to add jquery function to phpfox but no success. please suggest me proper way of adding jquery function to phpfox.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
   $Behaviour.onLoadEvents = function(){

     }
   $Behavior.onClickEvents = function() {
        };

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("div").click(function() {
        alert("Hello, world!");
      });
    });
```

no success with all of these three functions.
and getting an error

> SyntaxError: missing { before function body

on console window